# SQL Error 1630: Function SUBSTRING does not exist.. huh?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Right. So I've created a stored procedure in a MySQL DB which happens to use SUBSTRING.

Running the procedure via a query gives me:

> SQL Error 1630: Function mydatabase.SUBSTRING does not exist

Beg your pardon?

Comment: What do you get when you run: `SELECT version();`?

Comment: MySQL Version 5.1.41 - I'm running this using XAMPP on Windows XP.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are using it? Presumably in the code you aren't actually prefixing it with `mydatabase.`?

Comment: This is my UDF http://pastebin.com/nYdYBB7u and this is the query for the same http://pastebin.com/enky52Rf

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Is there a space after the method call to `Substring` before the first parenthesis?

It appears on Line 40:

```
 IF i > 1 AND j > 1 AND (s1_char = SUBSTRING (s2, j - 1, 1))
```

i.e. Ensure

```
select substring(CustomerName, 1, 4) AS CustName from MyTable;
```

instead of:

```
select substring (CustomerName, 1, 4) AS CustName from MyTable;
```

Comment: Bingo. Just tested that and that would seem to explain it!

Comment: Geez, whitespace sensitive !