# How i can get 2 digits (37) in 201010370311315 varchar in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have field called `nim(varchar)` in `t_mhs` table. It contains data like this:

```
nim
201010370311001
```

I want to select 2 number like:

```
nim
37
```

I use xampp v3.2.1 for database
and I ever use substring but this function does not exist

Comment: What's the criteria for selecting those two digits? Their position within the varchar?

Comment: Perhaps [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) would be helpful.

Comment: Is the number you want always two digits and in the same place?

Comment: yes,,,always two digits in the same place..

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('201010370311315', 7, 2);
```

Where:

- `7` is the position of the digits inside the whole number
- `2` is the number of digits

Comment: I use substring but this function does not exist

Comment: is there a space after `SUBSTRING` and before the first parenthesis? `SELECT SUBSTRING (...` won't work, `SELECT SUBSTRING(...` should. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507346/sql-error-1630-function-substring-does-not-exist-huh